# What's the API full process for subscribing a Facebook page to an app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to allow users to easily subscribe their Facebook page to my app (which uses webhooks).

I've found incomplete posts, largely talking about first gaining an access token for each page, but surely there must be a way to process this via the API, so it's easy for users? The process would be:

1. User clicks 'add my page' on my web platform
2. Redirects to Facebook, and asks user to select the page they wish to connect, and grant permission
3. Returns to my platform and adds the relevant info into the backend, ready for the incoming calls

Is there anywhere this flow is documented? I'm using the NodeJS SDK

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/#Creating

Comment: How do I get the page ID?

Comment: When the user has granted `pages_show_list` permission, you can make a request to `/me/accounts` using their token, to get a list of pages they have admin access to.

Comment: Are there any guides showing the chain of handoffs? I should probably understand it, but I'm not getting it. I've written plenty of API integrations, but I can't figure the FB one out!

Comment: Where is the problem? After the user granted your app permission, you make that request, get a list of their pages - and then you present those to them in a list, “pick one!” … and then you proceed with the page ID they chose in that step.

Comment: I'm missing something - How DOES the user grant my app permission?

Comment: Via the login dialog. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking